# How do I get the default CGRECT dimensions of uitableviewcell's detailtextlabel?

Tags: objective-c, uitableview

We're hoping to add a UIextLabel that replaces the default detailTextLabel of UITableViewCell's UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle.  I can get the UITextLabel to show however the problem is that I can't get it aligned as if it were a detailTextLabel.  The following code I've tried is this:

```
switch (indexPath.row) {
            case 1:{
                cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
                cell.detailTextLabel.numberOfLines = 1;
                //cell.detailTextLabel.text = @"Enter your display name";
                //self.displayNameTextField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(120, 13, 375, 30)];
                self.displayNameTextField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(cell.detailTextLabel.frame.origin.x, cell.detailTextLabel.frame.origin.y, cell.detailTextLabel.frame.size.height, cell.detailTextLabel.frame.size.width)];
                self.displayNameTextField.placeholder = @"Enter your display name";
                self.displayNameTextField.autocorrectionType = UITextAutocorrectionTypeNo;
                [self.displayNameTextField setClearButtonMode:UITextFieldViewModeWhileEditing];
                [cell addSubview:self.displayNameTextField];

                break;
            }
            default:
                break;
        }
```

Comment: Currently your UITextField is sized to the full frame of the cell.  Do you want the UILabel to be over (superimposed) the UITextField, or do you want the UILabel to be above the UITextField?

Comment: @Popmedic I'd like to either lay it over the detailTextLabel or get rid of the detailTextLabel and place the UITextField in its place instead.

Comment: Is `cell` a UITableViewCell, or are you using a custom derived class for `cell`?

Comment: @Popmedic yes its a UITableViewCell

Comment: When you initialize the creation of the cell you can use a style that does not have a detailTextLabel `cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue1 reuseIdentifier:"mycell"];`

Comment: @Popmedic this implementation does work however I'll need to troubleshoot how match the dimensions of a UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle.  Doing it this way resolves to a lot spacing in between the textLabel and the top of the UITableViewCellStyleValue1's cell.

Comment: Btw, if you use the other style, then be sure to remove any line the references detailTextLabel, ie `cell.detailTextLabel.numberOfLines = 1;`, it will be NULL, and you will get a crash.

Comment: Take a look at this tutorial https://medium.com/@satindersingh71/self-sizing-table-view-cells-programmatically-b0e82a20f264

Answer (score 0):

**A small correction in your code. You can use your own code withe some changes.**

Try this. It will work.

```
 switch (indexPath.row){
        case 1:{
            cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
            cell.detailTextLabel.numberOfLines = 1;
            UITextField *displayNameTextField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:cell.detailTextLabel.frame];
            displayNameTextField.placeholder = @"Enter your display name";
            displayNameTextField.autocorrectionType = UITextAutocorrectionTypeNo;
            [displayNameTextField setClearButtonMode:UITextFieldViewModeWhileEditing];
            [cell addSubview:displayNameTextField];
            break;
        }
        default:
            break;
    }
```